# Why can user have lower permissions than group or other? Who can change them?

Tags: permissions, root, chmod

It is my understanding that the owner of a file `user` can have lower permissions than `group` or `other`.

1. What is the justification for this?
2. Can only root and the owner change the permissions on a file?
3. If root removes permissions of the owner, can the owner add their permissions back with `chmod`?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking.  Can you give an example of file permissions and ownerships that illustrate what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This probably wouldn't happen but it's possible someone would do it to prevent themselves from accidentally modifying the file. They can't lock themselves out of a file they own, though, so it's more or less just a polite suggestion than an access control at that point.
2. Only the file owner or someone with `CAP_FOWNER` capability (which root has by default unless you add it to the bounding set) can change the permissions on a file. This behavior can be further restricted at the MAC level so that only certain security contexts can exercise these rights (so that, for example, `sshd` users couldn't `chmod` a particular type of file).
3. Yes. The owner is the one to whom maintenance of access controls has been delegated. They're assumed to be the ones best in a position to give or take away rights to other users.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
ls -la test
-rw-rw--r--   1 aadmin   aadmin        0 May 21 21:22 test
```

so user can read and write not execute this file, users form group can read and write also, others can read
So answering to your questions:

1. if i do `chmod u-w test`, then i cannot modify the file test because i have no write permission, if i do `chmod u+x` test i also cannot modify the file because i have no write permissions, so the permission can be lower but that have no much sense in terms of modifications of the file.
2. Yes, unless you have ACL spcified on that dir.
3. Yes if you are the owner you can change permission with chmod.